# Best way to create global god mode variables in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I want to have some "god mode" boolean toggles to quickly change functionality inside my app.

The previous developer created `#define` macros for these in a file that's included (indirectly) in every other file, but there are some disadvantages:

1. Every change has to be commited in git
2. Every change forces a build of the entire project

Is an `xconfig` file suited for this case? I accomplished what I want by:

1. Creating an `.xconfig` file
2. Adding it to the project
3. Adding `HACKS_TEST = YES` to it
4. Adding preprocessor macro `HACKS_TEST=${HACKS_TEST}` to the project target
5. Adding `static BOOL const IOHacksTest = HACKS_TEST`

and upon logging it, the value is printed correctly. But, if I change the `HACK_TEST`'s value in the `.xconfig` file, it still builds the entire project. Also, adding one 'hack', needs modifications in the `.xconfig` file, project target's preprocessor macro section and project's global file.

1. Is it possible to achieve this without the need of an entire project build?
2. Is there another solution that doesn't require these many modifications on new 'hacks' adding?
3. Is there another solution that is more appropriated to my needs and/or easier/better?
4. What is the best way to have them set to `NO` for the Release configuration?

**Edit:**

Along the selected solution, I also added this in the `Globals.m` file:

```
if #debug

BOOL IOHacksTest = YES;

#else

BOOL IOHacksTest = NO;

#endif
```

so for Release builds, all the "hacks" are turned off automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every change has to be commited in git

You can't, or really shouldn't try to, avoid this. If there's some setting that can affect how the whole project works, it should be archived with the project.

As you've discovered, putting the values in an .xcconfig file doesn't have much advantage over having #defines for everything - if you change the xcconfig file, yo have to rebuild everything.

To avoid that, you'll want to split the declaration and definition of the variables between a header and a source file. So, you'd have a goobals.h file that contains "extern" declarations, like this:

```
extern BOOL IOHacksTest;
```

And a goobals.m file that has:

```
BOOL IOHacksTest = YES;
```

Then you include goobals.h wherever you need the declarations. If you need to change a value, you only need to recompile a single file.

Comment: Let me explain myself better: I do want to commit in git for example the fact that a new "hack" was added that shows borders around `UIView`s, but not whether this is activated or not, because maybe I want it actived and my colleague wants it deactivated. Or I activate it to solve a bug and commit the related files and also the `.xconfig` file, and then I deactivate it to solve another bug and commit the related files and yet again the `.xconfig` file.

Comment: I took my inspiration from the [Habitica iOS project](https://github.com/HabitRPG/habitrpg-ios) which provides an `sample.debug.xconfig` file which you are supposed to copy it to `debug.xconfig` which is ignored from git, and you can safely enable and disable features without changing the working tree.

Comment: I finally understand your solution and successfully implemented it. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

> 1, Is it possible to achieve this without the need of an entire
>   project build?

If you want code to be compiled differently, based on those changing values, then there is no way to do it.  In fact, you **want** the project to be recompiled, because the generated code needs to change.

The best way to prevent an entire project build is to put those values into a header file, and selectively include that header file only in files that need to know about the values that could change.

> 2. Is there another solution that doesn't require these many modifications on new 'hacks' adding?

There is no way getting around it if you want compile-time detection.  If you change the values, then the compiler has to generate new code.  How could the compiler generate the right code if it does not know about the custom changes you want to make with your "changes?"

> 3. Is there another solution that is more appropriated to my needs and/or easier/better?

That depends on your actual needs, which you didn't state in the original question.  If you must have compile-time knowledge of the changes, you can use the header files, or you can add values to .xcconfig files, or just set them in the project.  However, you will still have to recompile all the code that is impacted every time the values change.

If you want the settings to be changed at run time, then this is precisely what `NSUserDefaults` is designed for.  Set an initial value in the source code, or in the Info.plist file, and set it to user-defaults on the app's first launch.  Thereafter, you can manage the values from user-defaults.

> 4. What is the best way to have them set to NO for the Release configuration?

```
static BOOL builtInDebugMode = !!(DEBUG);
```

**EDIT**

> Also, what does !!(DEBUG) do? – Iulian Onofrei

That's a logical-not operator, employed twice.  It ensures that its operand will always be either 1 or 0.  It was there to *guide* you to how it could be done (i.e., consider DEBUG or NDEBUG at compile time).

By default, your xcode configuration will have DEBUG=1 for debug builds.  You could set it to DEBUG=0 for release builds, and use the above code.

As long as your code properly handles DEBUG, this should be fine.  Unfortunately, some code incorrectly uses `#ifdef DEBUG` rather than `#if DEBUG` which could cause issues.

Thus, you may be better off with something like...

```
#if DEBUG
static BOOL builtInDebugMode = YES;
#else
static BOOL builtInDebugMode = NO;
#endif
```

When compiled in debug mode, DEBUG will be defined as 1.  When not in debug mode, it will not be defined at all.

Or, you could add a definition to your project file `DEBUG_VALUE`

Comment: Well, I don't really want to have this at compile time, I just haven't thought or any other way of doing it. My summed up question would also be "How others test the app? How do you easily go to level 10 without doing the first 9 levels? Isn't there a well-known method for these kind of cheats?". Also, what does `!!(DEBUG)` do?

Comment: As for how to do testing as you mention, that's a completely separate question.

Comment: I'm sorry, English is not my main language and I don't know how to best express myself regarding my question. The "god mode variables" from the title is referring to the same thing as "hacks" and "cheats" used for easy testing of an application, without the need of actually going through the app to reach a certain point. In my question I wrote part of my research, findings and starting idea. I'll soon update my question with a (hopefully) more concise and simple plain-text version.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei - Then I suggest you post another question, with detailed information about what you are trying to accomplish related to that topic.

Answer (score -2):

You can set some value in `NSUserDefault`, is very easy to use, I think.

You can add buttons to your app's UI to toggle these values, or you can let app query some website for this value at first launch, depends your needs.

NSUserDefault is fast.

And you can query at launch, and use it util app quit.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Elaborate. How to set it on a real device? How can I use those values and not query the user defaults plist everytime?

Comment: You can add buttons to your app's UI to toggle these values, or you can let app query some website for this value at first launch, depends your needs.  And why did you worry about query it overtime? `NSUserDefault` is fast,  and you can query at launch, and use it util app quit.

Comment: It's not faster than a `const`

Comment: So what? Why you need it so fast?